# nginx removes empty url parameters

Tags: url, nginx, parameters

I am using nginx as a reverse proxy on top of my REST webservices.

Don't know if this is REST conform but I would expect that an url in the form of:

```
https://<host>/api/v9/<method>/<param1>/<param2)/<param3>
```

with param1, param2 and param3 beeing optional arguments should process

```
https://<host>/api/v9/method1//argument2/argument3
```

with an empty argument for param1, which works if i call my webservice directly but won't work if nginx is acting as a proxy on top. In this case I will get argument2 as param1 and argument3 as param2 (what is wrong).

How can I configure nginx to pass "empty" parameters (or url parts) as empty?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Multiple consecutive `/`s in a path are normalised to a single `/` in `nginx`. Other web servers may behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to not compress the uri before doing location matching.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#merge_slashes